# How should the enum type look like in the bottom part of a UML diagram?

Tags: class, uml, enumeration, accessor, mutators

I know what the enum type should look like in the middle section of a UML diagram but how should it look in the bottom section where it contains the actions/methods of the class? Isn't there accessors and mutators for enum types?

[image: Problem with Enum Type]

Comment: I should imagine "+ GetTypeOfAttack:TypeOfAttack"

Comment: which means public accessible method returning an enum of type TypeOfAttack. You probably also need a field in destroyer to store its TypeOfAttack

Comment: Oh... You have that as in "Attack"

Comment: Looking at other examples on the net (and without pulling my book on UML) it is almost certainly "+ GetTypeOfAttack:TypeOfAttack". + or - denote public/private field/method, parameters are expressed between () and return type is specified after :

Comment: @PaulSullivan: Yes, that is correct. However, would it be the same for a accessor? Something like this "+ setAttack(TypeOfAttack Attack): void"

Comment: You should think of an accessor just as a field (UML is just about expressing the connections not how it works) ... You call the method and it returns a value... some methods have no parameters so can be thought of just as fields even though there MAY be code in there

Comment: Not in the classical sense

Comment: Ill create an answer and try explain these ideas

Answer (score 1):

```
+GetTypeOfAttack:TypeOfAttack
```

Is probably the answer but you need to ask yourself a question about whether this is a 'classic' accessor mutator

A classic accessor/mutator (getter/setter) is usually like the following

```
private bool hiddenField = true;

//Accessor
public bool GetHiddenField()
{
     return hiddenField;
}

//mutator
public void SetHiddenField(bool input)
{
    hiddenField = input;
}
```

BUT you may (more often than not) have situations where you need to do some logic evaluation before either getting or setting the field... This is not a pure accessor/mutator but essentially it is.

In answer to your question:

```
+SetHiddenField(bool): void
+GetHiddenField:bool
```

See how they map to the previous code. +/- = public/private, (denoteParameters) and : denotes return type

Comment: You just wrote to me
+getType: Type  --> +GetTypeOfAttack:TypeOfAttack
I believe for accessors it should look like:
+getStoringVariable: Type --> +getAttack: TypeOfAttack
Right??

You just made a visual example above!
+GetHiddenField:bool

Comment: I'm sorry... I don't get what you are trying to express. It really doesn't matter what you call the accessor/mutator other than it should be self describing (describes what the field/method does) and case also doesn't matter. i.e. in java it should (by convention) be lower camel case "getTheType:typeOfAttack" or i.e. in c# it is usually (by convention) upper camel case "GetTheType:TypeOfAttack". It depends on your target platform (but don't worry too much about it ;)

Comment: @user1753668 ... any joy? Remember to mark answers and if you need more clarification just ask.